# What transfers from the demo to the main game?

Tags: legend-of-legacy

What transfers from the *Legend of Legacy* demo to the main version of the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game will pick up where you leave off in the demo. To do this takes an extra step as the game will not import data from the demo. In order to export your demo save to the main game you need to have at least 1 session left on your demo counter.

1. Start by launching the main *The Legend of Legacy* game. Let it create game data.
2. Once you reach the start screen, quit the game.
3. Open the demo and choose the export option on the bottom of the main menu.
4. Choose a save slot in the main game to place your data.
5. Save.
6. Quit the demo and open the main game.

You can now play from where you left off. I haven't found any bonuses from playing the demo first like in other games.